# How do I make the link for Switcher Panel reflect 'show' class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am using jQuery Content Panel Switcher https://code.google.com/p/jquery-content-panel-switcher/

By adding the class 'show', you can determine which content/panel shows on load, but how do I make that reflect in the links that choose the content/panel.

Basically, if panel 1 is show, link 1 should be red.

I am already using this to change the link after the click

```
     $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.nav_buttons a').click(function(event){
        $('.nav_buttons a').css({ 'background-color' : '' }); //clear past selections
        $(this).css({ 'background-color' : 'red' }); //set new selection
    });    
  });
```

Comment: Do you want to change the color of links with clicking on different panels?

Comment: On load, I want the link to show which panel is open, then they would change after that depending on which was clicked.

Comment: Some more code with content panel switcher could help me to understand the situation.

Comment: Check out http://jsfiddle.net/n4pPy/1/

Comment: You may check if it solves the issue.
http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/n4pPy/5/

Comment: While your solution is independent of the 'show' class in the panel, it totaly works! Post it as an answer and I'll give you credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On first time page load just the default link that loads can be explicitly bind with a certain (css)class attribute and then on each click event the class attribute of the links can be changed accordingly using jQuery.

First remove all the class attributes of the links

```
$('.nav_buttons a').removeClass('selected');
```

Then add the specific css class that makes the navigation background color change

```
$(this).addClass('selected');
```

Here's a full demonstration on [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/n4pPy/5/)